# Where did Aaron bathe his body in Leviticus 16:24?

Tags: leviticus

English Standard Version

> Leviticus 16:23 Then Aaron shall come into the **tent of meeting** and shall take off the linen garments that he put on when he went into the Holy Place and shall leave them there.
> 24 And he shall **bathe his body in water in a holy place** and put on his garments and come out and offer his burnt offering and the burnt offering of the people and make atonement for himself and for the people.

It seems that Aaron bathed inside the tent of meeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the courtyard of the tabernacle, that is outside the tent of meeting but still in the courtyard, there were two items:

- the altar of burnt offering (Ex 27:1-8, 38:1-7, 40:6-8)
- and the large bronze laver (Ex 30:17-21, 38:8, 39:9, 39, 40:7, 11, 30-32) for washing.

The Bronze laver contained water for priests to ceremonially wash as required under the tabernacle regulations.  The Yom Kippur, or "Day of Atonement" also contained regulations (Lev 16) for such priestly washing (Lev 16:24) as part of the ceremony.

Later, in the Solomon's temple, the laver became much larger - so large it was called a "sea", 1 Kings 7:23-26, 44.  Solomon also built 10 smaller lavers (to accommodate the larger numbers of priests needed), 1 Kings 7:38, 39., 43.

Answer (score 1):

Where did Aaron bathe his body in Leviticus 16:24?

**In the tent of meeting" the reason being.**

Exodus 30:20  (NASB)

20 when they enter the tent of meeting, they shall wash with water, so that they will not die; or when they approach the altar to minister, by offering up in smoke a fire sacrifice to the Lord.